# How to implement Promise.all like functionality in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

Am trying to get messages from twillio server using its sdk method so on calling the method it return callback to return the List of messages. I have list of conversation,i want to get all messages for conversation so am using forEach like this

```
  allConversations.forEach { conversation ->
            conversation.getMessageByIndex(conversation.lastMessageIndex){
                conversationLastMessages[conversation.sid] = it
            }
        }
```

So i want to wait until all listners get executed and then want to change the state of ui.

Comment: Is this `getMessageByIndex()` synchronous or asynchronous? Does it wait for the operation to finish and then executes passed block of code or it schedules operation in the background, returns immediately and invokes passed lambda when finished? Is this operation suspendable? Do you invoke it from a coroutine context? Because you tagged the question with coroutines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make all requests in parallel and wait for all of them to finish following next steps:

1. Create a `suspend` function `getMessage`, which will be responsible for suspending the calling coroutine until request is executed. You can use `suspendCoroutine` or `suspendCancellableCoroutine` for that:

   ```
   suspend fun getMessage(conversation: Conversation) = suspendCoroutine<Message?> { continuation ->
       conversation.getMessageByIndex(conversation.lastMessageIndex, object : CallbackListener<Message> {
           override fun onError(errorInfo: ErrorInfo) {
               continuation.resume(null) // resume calling coroutine
               // or continuation.resumeWithException() depend whether you want to handle Exception or not
           }

           override fun onSuccess(result: Message) {
               continuation.resume(result) // resume calling coroutine
           }
       })
   }
   ```
2. Run requests in parallel using `async` coroutine builder and `Dispatchers.IO` dispatcher to offload work from the Main Thread:

   ```
   async(Dispatchers.IO) {
       getMessage(conversation)
   }
   ```
3. To run all this you need to use some instance of `CoroutineScope` to launch a coroutine. In `ViewModel` it can be `viewModelScope`, in `Activity`/`Fragment` - `lifecycleScope`. For example in `ViewModel`:

   ```
   viewModelScope.launch {
       val allConversations = ...

       allConversations.map { conversation ->
           async(Dispatchers.IO) {
               getMessage(conversation)
           }
       }.awaitAll() // waiting for all request to finish executing in parallel
        .forEach { message ->   // iterate over List<Message> and fill conversationLastMessages
            conversationLastMessages[message.getConversationSid()] = message
        }

        // here all requests are completed and UI can be updated
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answers, i ve a question is that i want to get my response data class but after awaitAll() call inside the forEach i got Unit but can't convert it to my response class, can u help me with that? I am using Retrofit2 and OnResponse `continuation.resume(response.body())` @Sergio

Comment: @Tarık please create a separate question on stackoverflow with details and send link here, I will try to help, thanks.